# Correctly concatenating lists intro a big data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I have this piece of code

```
import glob
all_filenames=glob.glob('13*.VisNO2A')
all_filenames.sort()

for filename in all_filenames:
    data=read_datafile(filename) #this is a fuction I defined earlier-works good
    appended_data = pd.concat([data],axis=0)
    df1=pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
    print(df1)
```

I want the result to be a big data frame with all files' data sorted by timestamp.I am doing something wrong ? When I do df1.to_excel() it is exporting just part of the data, not all of it. Many thanks.

Comment: You are not appending anything. You are redefining the variable `appended_data` at each iteration. Only the most recent value holds. Initialize `appended_data` as an empty dataframe and then change it with `appended_data = pd.concat([appended_data,data])` (note that this is a very bad solution, but it will at least work).

Comment: I did "appended_data=pd.DataFrame()" and then  "appended_data = pd.concat([appended_data,data])" , I exported again, same.

Comment: You saved `appended_data` to the file _outside_ of the loop, I assume? (Scrap the `df1` stuff from your code, it is useless.)

Comment: No, it was inside the loop. I tried both methods, same results.